# Failed to match variable with string value

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have simple below script

```
#!/bin/bash

RESPONSE=`jq '.errorCode' /data/logs/errorLog.log`
echo $RESPONSE
if [[ "$RESPONSE" = "INVALID_API_CREDENTIALS" ]]
then
        echo "Registration unsuccessful..."
else
        echo "Registration successful..."
fi
```

Output

```
root@ubuntu-test:/data/logs# ./test.sh
"INVALID_API_CREDENTIALS"
Registration successful...
root@gubuntu-test:/data/logs#
```

Why else block is executing here?

Comment: In your variable, the double-quotes are *part of* the string, but in the string you're comparing it to the double-quotes are *around* the string. Try `if [[ "$RESPONSE" = '"INVALID_API_CREDENTIALS"' ]]` (here, the single-quotes are around the string, making the double-quotes part of the string). Also, `echo $variable` can be misleading for several reasons; see ["I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else).

Comment: You are using the Bash string comparison operator in a wrong way. It is a double equal sign `==` rather than a single one `=`.

Comment: @MartinTovmassian No. In bash, `=` and `==` are equivalent inside `[[…]]`

Comment: And in fact, the POSIX-compatible comparison operator is a single `=`

Comment: Side-note, specifying `set -x` below the `#!` script header is very useful to debug these type of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Guess it's clear what went wrong from Gordon Davisson comment. Just want to add that `jq -r ...` also could fix this. And I'd suggest to use bash regex `=~` instead of `=` it could save some space:

```
if [[ $RESPONSE =~ INVALID ]]
then
        echo "Registration unsuccessful..."
else
        echo "Registration successful..."
fi
```

It could also be case insensitive with `shopt -s nocasematch`

Comment: Alternatively, `[[ $RESPONSE = INVALID* ]]`